# Disable Javascript effect based on the screen's size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just made a search bar which expands after a click on the search icon (this is made in javascript). Now doing the responsive design, I want to disable the javascript. Im now coming to you to try to find a to disable a javascript effect.

My source code is here for you to try it, make sure you reduice the size of the screen for the responsive to take effect.

```css
body{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header-two-bars{
 font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header-two-bars .header-limiter{
 max-width: 1200px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Logo */

.header-two-bars h1{
 float: left;
 font: normal 35px Cookie, Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin: 0;
}

.header-two-bars h1 span {
 color: #5383d3;
}

/* The first bar */

.header-two-bars .header-first-bar{
 background-color:#292c2f;
 box-shadow:0 1px 1px #ccc;
 padding: 20px 40px;
 height: 80px;
 color: #ffffff;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-two-bars .header-first-bar a {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.member-area-buttons {
 float: right;
}

.signup-button, .login-user, .login-designer {
 font-size: 13px;
 float: left;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: #5383d3;
 color: white;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 border: 1px solid #5E6367;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.signup-button:hover, .login-user:hover, .login-designer:hover{
 background-color:#2B5773;
}
 
.signup-button{
 padding-top: 10px;
 margin-top: 0;
 border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #6caee0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    border: 0;
}
/*social-button*/
/*
.header-two-bars .header-first-bar nav i.fa {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 35px;
 height: 35px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color:  #33383b;
 border-radius: 2px;

 font-size: 20px;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 35px;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: 3px;
}
*/

/* Second Bar */

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
 padding: 20px 40px;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar h2 {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 color: #292c2f;
 font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar h2 a {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #4e5359;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav {
 text-align: right;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a{
 display: inline-block;
 color: #4e5359;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
 padding-right: 12px;
}


 
.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a:last-child{
 color: red;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a:hover{
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #2B5773;
 padding-top:8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 color: white;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a.selected{
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #2B5773;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 color: white;
}

.header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav i.fa {
 color: #A9B7BF;
 margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}
 
/* Responsive Design */

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {

 .header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav{
  font-size:14px;
 }
 
 .header-two-bars .header-first-bar h1 {
   font-size: 29px;
   margin-left: -10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
 }
 
}

@media all and (max-width:590px) {

 .header-two-bars .header-first-bar{
  height: 120px;
  padding:20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;

 }

 
 .header-two-bars .header-first-bar h1 {
  float: none;
  margin: -8px 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
 }
 
 /*social-button
 
 .social-button {
  float:left;
 }

 .header-two-bars .header-first-bar nav i.fa {
  
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
  
 }
 */
 
 .signup-button, .login-user, .login-designer  {
  
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 .header-two-bars .header-second-bar{
  padding: 20px 0;
 }
 
}

@media all and (max-width: 610px) {
 .header-two-bars .header-second-bar h2{
  float:none;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
 }

 .header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav{
  text-align: center;
 }

 .header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav a{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
 }

 .header-two-bars .header-second-bar nav i.fa{
  margin-left:0;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 465px) {
 .header-two-bars .header-first-bar{
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 15px;

 }

 .signup-button, .login-user, .login-designer  {
  
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #5E6367;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 76px
 }
 
 .signup-button{
  padding-top:10px;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
 
 .header-two-bars .header-first-bar{
  height: 180px;
 }
 /*Social Button
 .social-button {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
 */
 
 
 .member-area-buttons {
  float:none;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 
 /*.signup-button, .login-user,*/ .login-designer {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .signup-button {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 .login-user {
  float:right;
  margin-right:10px;
 }
}


/* The search box */

.header-search form {
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 right: 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color:  #3a3c3e;
 width: 44px;
 height: 40px;
 cursor: pointer;

 -ms-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

/* CSS search icon */

.header-search form:before {
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 width: 9px;
 height: 9px;
 top: 12px;
 left: 14px;
}

.header-search form:after {
 position: absolute;
 content: '';
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 2px;
 height: 8px;
 top: 22px;
 left: 26px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-44deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-44deg);
 transform: rotate(-44deg);
}

/* The search box */

.header-search form input {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 42px;
 padding: 11px 12px 9px;
 border: none;
 width: 210px;
 border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
 height: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

/* Making the header responsive. */

@media all and (max-width: 590px) {

 .header-search form {
  float: left;
  left: 5px;
 }

}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {

 .header-search form {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  top: 20px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 78%;
  
 }

 .header-search form input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .stop_javascript {
  display: none;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 300px) {
 .header-search form {
  left: 9px;
 }
}
```

```html
<header class="header-two-bars">

   <div class="header-first-bar">
    <div class="header-limiter">
     <h1><a href="#">Africa<span>Fashion</span></a></h1>
     <div class="member-area-buttons">
      <a href="form-register.html" class="signup-button">Sign Up</a>
      <a href="form-login-designer.html" class="login-designer">Login <br/> Designer</a>
      <a href="form-login-user.html" class="login-user">Login <br/> User</a>
     </div>
     
     
     <div class="header-search">
      <form method="get" action="#">
       <input type="search" placeholder="Search!" name="search">
      </form>
     </div>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script>

                      $(document).ready(function() {

       $('.header-search form').on('click', function(e) {

        // If the form (which is turned into the search button) was
        // clicked directly, toggle the visibility of the search box.

        if(e.target == this) {
         $(this).find('input').toggle();
        }

       });
      });

     </script>

    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="header-second-bar">
    <div class="header-limiter">
     <h2><a href="#">Hi,</a></h2>
     <nav>
      <a href="content/index.html"><i class="fa fa-male"></i> Men</a>
      <a href="content/index.html" class="selected"><i class="fa fa-female"></i> Women</a>
      <a href="content/index.html"><i class="fa fa-folder-o"></i> Latest Collection</a>
      <a href="content/index.html"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Designers</a>
      <a href="content/index.html"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color: red;"></i> Northern Fashion</a> <!-- It should be red-->
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>

  </header>
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean to disable the enable/disable searchbox based on screen size or want to disable js. Since on disabling js will be kind of blackout

Comment: On the big screen, when the user clicks on the search button, the searchbox expands and this was made in javascript. What I was try to do, it is to get the full bar when i am on the small screen (phone screen) and disable the javascript effect as there is no need to expand the search bar on the small screen.

Sorry i am not a native english speaker, Im trying my best. thanks

Comment: Can you add this on JsFiddle.net please?

Comment: The source code is available here, check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/7c5aL2ja/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try checking the window width before you run toggle (you'll want to change minWidth to the minimum width you want for your application):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.header-search form').on('click', function(e) {

        // If the form (which is turned into the search button) was
        // clicked directly, toggle the visibility of the search box.

        if(e.target == this && window.innerWidth > minWidth) {
            $(this).find('input').toggle();
        }

    });
});
```